# MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner throwing error while trying to execute GIT SCM

Tags: .net, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am trying to analyse .NET project using MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner. The project is stored in GIT source control. When SCM adapter is enabled, the analysis fails at step when sonar is trying to get SCM blame information. I am using GIT SCM provider plugin version 1.1. Please advise.

4:24:34 PM  16:24:34.993 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor

4:24:34 PM  16:24:34.993 INFO  - SCM provider for this project is: git

4:24:34 PM  16:24:34.999 INFO  - 3 files to be analyzed

4:24:35 PM  INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

4:24:35 PM  INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE

4:24:35 PM  INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

4:24:35 PM  Total time: 32.047s

4:24:35 PM  Final Memory: 16M/64M

4:24:35 PM  INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

4:24:35 PM  ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution

4:24:35 PM  ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar

4:24:35 PM  ERROR: Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: 
org.eclipse.jgit.diff.DiffConfig

4:24:35 PM  ERROR: Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.diff.DiffConfig

Thanks,

Sukhveer

Comment: Which SonarQube and Java versions are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This was because of java version. Earlier it was pointing to IBM java 1.7.0. I changed the java_home to different JRE (1.7.0.75) and SCM scan finished successfully.